# KeyError: 'payment_publisher.publish_payment_data' when using Celery

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq, celery

I'm encountering an error while working with Celery 5.2.7 in my Python project. The error message and traceback are as follows:

```
The delivery info for this task is:
{'consumer_tag': 'None4', 'delivery_tag': 1, 'redelivered': False, 'exchange': '', 'routing_key': 'celery'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rodolphe/primetel_project/primetel/Backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 591, in on_task_received
    strategy = strategies[type_]
KeyError: 'payment_publisher.publish_payment_data'
```

I'm trying to execute a task named 'payment_publisher.publish_payment_data', but it seems that the task is not recognized by Celery. I have already checked the following:

The task is imported in my code, and the module containing the task is properly imported.
The task is registered with Celery using the correct name.
However, I'm still facing this error. Can anyone please help me understand why this error is occurring and how to resolve it?

here is my rabbitmq configuration code

```
import pika
from broker.payment_brocker.messagin_config_interface import MessagingConfigInterface

class RabbitMQConfig(MessagingConfigInterface):

    def __init__(self, host='localhost', queue_name='payment_data', port='15672'):
        self.host = host
        self.queue_name = queue_name
        self.port = port

    def get_broker_url(self):
        # Return the RabbitMQ broker URL
        return f'amqp://{self.host}:{self.port}'

    def get_queue(self):
        # Return the task queue configuration
        return {
            'name': self.queue_name,
            'routing_key': self.queue_name,
        }
        
    def create_connection(self):
        # Create a connection to RabbitMQ
        return pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(self.host, self.port))

    def declare_queue(self, channel):
        # Declare the queue
        channel.queue_declare(queue=self.queue_name)
```

and my celery code:

file: send_payment_data.py

```
from broker.payment_brocker.rabbitmq_config import RabbitMQConfig
import json
from celery import Celery

rabbitmq_config = RabbitMQConfig()
connection = rabbitmq_config.create_connection()
channel = connection.channel()
rabbitmq_config.declare_queue(channel)

app = Celery('payment_publisher')
# Load RabbitMQ configuration
rabbitmq_config = RabbitMQConfig()

# Configure Celery to use RabbitMQ as the message broker
app.conf.broker_url = rabbitmq_config.get_broker_url()

@app.task
def publish_payment_data(payment_data):
    channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                          routing_key=rabbitmq_config.queue_name,
                          body=json.dumps(payment_data))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    payment_data = {'patient_id': 1, 'amount': 100}
    #publish_payment_data.delay(payment_data)
    result = publish_payment_data.delay(payment_data)
    print("Task ID:", result.id)
    print("[x] Sent 'Hello World!'")
```

Any guidance or suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you!